# Winsock recv loop not functioning correctly

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock

For some reason when I connect to my C++ server with Putty I get this

```
Recv: (string I typed)
Recv:
```

This happens everytime I send characters to my server using Putty

Source follows.  If nessicary I will post the rest of my source. TYIA -Roland

```
    void recvthread( void *pParams )    {

        char buffer[128]

        int err;
        bool gonow = true;

        while( true )   {

           memset( buffer, '\0', 128 );


           err = -1;
           err = recv( datasock, buffer, 128, 0 );


            if( err != -1 ) {

              std::cout << "Recv: " << buffer << '\n';
              std::cout << "Err = " << err << '\n';
           }

        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I get this:

```
Recv: (string I typed)
Recv:
```

You get the string you typed plus whatever else was left over in the buffer from the previous time. If `err` is positive it is the number of bytes actually received. If it is zero it means the peer has disconnected and you should stop reading. Don't ignore these values.

Comment: It's an excellent bet that `err == 0` here, because the client disconnected. You're right that the code shouldn't go back around for another loop if `err < 0`, though.